# Не работает setClickable в Spinner

Tags: android

Я нахожу и настраиваю `Spinner` вот так:

```
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.work_with_words_spinner_1);
        spinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_background);
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.words_forms, R.layout.custom_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setSelection(0);
        spinner.setClickable(false);
```

Но `setClickable(false);` почему-то не работает! Пункты `Spinner'a` все равно раскрываются! Но почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте просто его отключить:

```
spinner.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Уху! То что нужно!